# Only Execute on Certain Frames in SFML

Tags: c++, frame, sfml

I am still fairly new to SFML, and right now I am trying to make a basic scrolling plane game. I've got most of the basic stuff down, but I'm beginning to notice that the screen looks laggy. I'm using the window.setFrameRateLimit function so that the result of movement is the same on all computers, but it makes random lag spikes happen while the program is executing. I think it's doing this because of the limit on the frame rate, and because of how it does that. Is there another better way to only have the program execute at certain times? Ideally, it would also move at the same speed on slower computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the setFrameRateLimit lag spikes was fixed in SFML 2.0. If you cannot upgrade to SFML 2.0, then you can add your own frame rate limiter. This involves adding a sleep() to your game loop. For example:

```
while(App.IsOpened()) {
   float time = Clock.GetElapsedTime();

   // update game
   // draw game

   float timeToWait = (1.0 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND) - (Clock.GetElapsedTime() - time);
   if(timeToWait > 0) {
       sleep(timeToWait * 1000);
   }
}
```